# Hiding parent when child label has a certain "for"?

Tags: css

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="field configurable required">
    <label class="label" for="attribute300">...</label>
</div>
<div class="field configurable required">
    <label class="label" for="attribute400">...</label>
</div>
...
```

Now, I want to hide the first div, but it does not exist on every page, so it must be hidden in combination with the `for="attribute300"`. Possible with plain CSS?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible using [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), but check browser support. (Not available in Firefox yet, unless explicitly enabled by the user.)

Comment: Thanks, how would it look in case if the "for"?

Comment: `div:has([for="attribute300"])` will do the trick. (You could add the `.label` class or the tag name as well, but since the `for` attribute only occurs on labels, it is doubtful you'll encounter a situation where that additional distinction would actually be necessary.)

Comment: In the real situation might there be other elements in the div, before and after the label and/or text nodes (ie text not in an element of its own?). Could you give a fuller example of the possible HTML if so?

Answer (score -2):

```
div.field >
  .label[for="attribute300"] {
  display: none;
}
```

You can make this way, but it will be hidden in all scenarios.

code: https://codepen.io/Suryaprakash-the-vuer/pen/dywBRwW

Comment: The attribute is not set on the div itself, but on the label it contains.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working ... sure this is the way to go? I do not only want to hide the label, but the parent of the label including the label.

Comment: @user4095519 Check the edited answer, This should work

Comment: It would hide the label, but like I said, I want to hide the parent of the label as well, including the label.

Comment: Try putting some additional content in the div (not in the label), it will still be visible.